# What is "helpx_last_check" from wordpress database

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am a developer who works full time with wordpress and I came across something in my database which I have never seen before.  I tried the normal search engine approach and have found nothing.  Wondering if the wonderful people of stackoverflow have seen this before.  I am pretty sure it isn't harmful.  This is the entry in the mysql database.

Table is "_options"

```
option_id: 1165
blog_id: 0
option_name: helpx_last_check   
option_value: 1276628545    
autoload: yes
```

I am specifically wondering what "helpx_last_check" is.
Thanks

Comment: What version of WP are you running? Do you have any plugins installed, and/or have run plugins in the past?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you (or did you) have the [MapPress Easy Google Maps plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mappress-google-maps-for-wordpress/) installed? This includes some `helpx` plugin options, but I haven't investigated what they check. If it's not this plugin, search your code for a class called `helpx`, maybe others use it too.

Comment: Thanks for your help...I actually installed it about a week ago. Perfect...now if anyone else has this question they can find it here or through google. (since they couldn't before)  Thanks Jan